# Can the Secretary of Defence sack Generals and appoint new ones?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, military

In this highly controversial time, some Democrats are suggsting that Trump might use the power the military to retain power, and that this would constitute a military coup, and that Trump's appointment of new civilian leaders of the Pentagon is a staging post on the road to this.

Some people suggest that this wouldn't be possible, because civilian leaders can't just issue any order to military generals and expect it to be complied with.

My question is, can the DoD officials simply sack the generals and replace them with other generals who would be more co-operative?  Or is there a more complex process than this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while it contains the core of a good question I don't have the energy to clean up the partisan attack language.

Comment: @Jontia a very good point.  Sorry, I was tired when I wrote it.  I have re-written it to make it ideologically-neutral

Comment: @SurpriseDog I honestly wouldn't discount the possibility at this point in time.  Except that I doubt he's clever enough to pull it off.  His entire Presidency has been a series of missed opportunities (from his supporters' perspective).  Witness how the alt-Right has abandoned him.

Comment: @SurpriseDog I agree that a military coup is almost certainly not going to happen - at least this time around. But to say this is no big deal is hopelessly naive. He is saying, flat out, that he’s the winner, that will remain president, and that the democratic process is illegitimate. And every Republican in office agrees with him! There’s no one giving more than the most mealy-mouthed disapproval of this rejection of the most basic principle of democracy

Comment: Eventually the court will rule one way or another and that will be the end of it. People read too many opinion pieces and get wrapped up in the narrative.

Comment: @SurpriseDog why would it be the end of it? Is Roe vs Wade over? Obergefell v Hodges? Obamacare?

Answer (score 9):

The Commander in Chief can discharge anyone in the army for reasons such as "unsuitability". But the President can only appoint Generals with the advice and consent of the Senate. By law, he can only appoint suitably qualified candidates (ie serving senior military officers) except at a time of war. This makes it difficult for the President to simply fire all the Generals and put "yes-men" in their places.

Perhaps it is worth noting that the military oath is to the constitution, not to the President.  Soldiers swear to obey the commands of the President "according to the regulations".  So illegal or unconstitutional commands are still illegal and must not be obeyed.

Comment: In fact, soldiers have a _duty_ not to obey illegal orders, which is rather different from having an _option_ not to obey them as stated here.  In other words, the last sentence should read "...must not be obeyed."

Comment: @phoog the reality is that most people who take the oath could care less. They will obey and follow any order because "i'm just doing my job" and "my boss told me to". Courage to stand up to something wrong when its being done by an authority figure is almost nonexistent in modern americans. Invading random countries without Congress declaring war is severely unconstitutional, but everyone allowed it without a second thought. And there will be someone who comes on here and tries to defend the unconstitutional invasions, but if you can read english you can read the docs for yourself.

Comment: Most US military members wouldn't know an illegal/unconstitutional order if it hit them in the face. The number of them that have actually read the constitution is probably less than 1%. The good news is, whatever that number is, its probably an order of magnitude higher than the percentage of american citizens that have read that doc.

Comment: What do you mean "could care less"?  Do you mean "couldn't care less"?

Comment: @JamesK In common usage, [both "Could care less" and "Couldn't care less" mean the same thing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/could-couldnt-care-less), at least in the US

Comment: I never knew that!  That makes no sense to me...but I know language isn't logical.   That is not just illogical it is "head over heels" counterfactual...  Oh well.  I'm pretty sure that in the UK it is always "couldn't care less"

Comment: Could he simply sack generals without replacing them, until he reached someone low enough down the command chain who would obey his orders?

Comment: Who knows.  It all becomes very speculative.  If he is willing to do that, then he's willing just to ignore the constitution completely.

Comment: @Statsanalyst entertaining your hypothesis: that would amount to depriving the US army of its most qualified leadership, putting US lives and interests at risk everywhere in the world. My guess is that a president trying this would be impeached before he succeeds: even the most extreme Republicans don't want to make the US army headless and therefore highly vulnerable.

Comment: @JamesK Since were discussing military coups, I think that would be a given in any hypothetical here.m

Comment: @Erwan First, the idea that Republicans would turn on Trump while he holds any power is laughable. Aside from that, in this hypothetical, Trump just led a successful military coup - with the Army behind him, he couldn’t be impeached even if they wanted to

Comment: @divibisan in this hypothetical, he is replacing the military leadership in order to pull a military coup, so he hasn't succeeded yet. By casually sacking many high ranking and respected army leaders, it would be very hard for him to pretend that all these people are horrible democrats. Therefore he is more likely to lose the support of the army, and many people will see this as very unpatriotic. That would go very very much against Republican values.

Comment: "*...except at a time of war*", some newspaper articles say he could start a war with Iran in the meantime...

Comment: @johndoe, I do not know the details of your education, but the public schools I attended required reading of the Constitution in both 8th grade and 11th grade American History, So I can safely say that 100% of my high school graduating class has read the Constitution. I will not claim that they all have a complete understanding, nor do I believe all remember it all, but your claim about 1% of the military members, and less than that for the general population, having read the Constitution seems to be made up out of whole cloth.

Comment: @johndoe: That surprises me. The US Constitution is required reading in my country on the other side of the world, but not in the US?

Comment: @JörgWMittag No, it is also not required reading in German schools

Comment: @JamesK *If he is willing to do that, then he's willing just to ignore the constitution completely* Well yes, we knew that.